# proper routing for api namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

The following routes are defined in the rails routes.rb file:

```
require 'apiconstraints'

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json }, constraints: { subdomain: 'api' }, path: '/'  do
    scope module: :v1, constraints: Apiconstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
      resources :buildings, only: [:show, :index] do
```

I also attempted to define the path with a blank:

```
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json }, constraints: { subdomain: 'api' }, path: ''  do
```

to no avail.
nginx sites-enabled file is configured as such:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.thedomain.ws [...] thedomain.ws www.thedomain.ws
```

`api.thedomain.ws` responds.  However, if I call  `api.thedomain.ws/v1/buildings`  rails returns a No route matches [GET] "/v1/buildings"

For completeness:

```
class Apiconstraints
  def initialize(options)
    @version = options[:version]
    @default = options[:default]
  end

  def matches?(req)
    @default || req.headers['Accept'].include?("application/vnd.v4.v#{@version}")
  end
end
```

what am I missing here?

Comment: try `api/v1/buildings`

Comment: No route matches [GET] "/api/v1/buildings"

Answer (score 4):

The `namespace` macro adds a "namespace" to the path:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    resources :things
  end
end
```

---

```
        Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
    api_things GET    /api/things(.:format)          api/things#index
               POST   /api/things(.:format)          api/things#create
 new_api_thing GET    /api/things/new(.:format)      api/things#new
edit_api_thing GET    /api/things/:id/edit(.:format) api/things#edit
     api_thing GET    /api/things/:id(.:format)      api/things#show
               PATCH  /api/things/:id(.:format)      api/things#update
               PUT    /api/things/:id(.:format)      api/things#update
           DELETE /api/things/:id(.:format)      api/things#destroy
```

Which is the main point of using it. Don't confuse the Rails concept of routing namespaces with the language level feature of module nesting.

If you just want to nest the controllers in a module or add constraints use `scope` instead:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope module: :api do
    resources :things
  end
end
```

---

```
    Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                Controller#Action
    things GET    /things(.:format)          api/things#index
           POST   /things(.:format)          api/things#create
 new_thing GET    /things/new(.:format)      api/things#new
edit_thing GET    /things/:id/edit(.:format) api/things#edit
     thing GET    /things/:id(.:format)      api/things#show
           PATCH  /things/:id(.:format)      api/things#update
           PUT    /things/:id(.:format)      api/things#update
           DELETE /things/:id(.:format)      api/things#destroy
```

So in your case you want:

```
scope defaults: { format: :json }, module: :api, constraints: { subdomain: 'api' } do
  scope module: :v1, constraints: Apiconstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
    resources :buildings, only: [:show, :index]
  end
end
```

Comment: IHMO I would just use a path for the version instead of headers or whatever Apiconstraints does. It just works.

Comment: usefully detailed explanation.  which confirms my confusion about many better practices that suggest the above `https://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2013/06/13/building-awesome-rails-apis-part-1`, for example

Comment: also updated question for completeness as I am still getting a no route matches error

Comment: Your actual goal is pretty unclear. If you are using the `Accept-Type` header for versioning it does not make sense to have the version in the path so the above will mount the resource as `api.hostname.tld/buildings`. Use the `rails routes` command to see the actual routes generated.

Comment: You should also include as much details about how you made the request as possible. Did you send it via cURL? Did you make sure to set the Accept-Type header? Include the rails log.

Comment: is correct in both pointing out the deficiencies in the question regarding request to api and particularly to "just use a path for the version"  the header can be kept shortened to an access control token and reduce clutter.

Comment: Typically you would a `Authorization` header and not `Accept-Type` for authentication. `Accept-Type` is supposed to be used by the client to tell the server what sort of response it expects back but someone thought it was a good idea to use it for versioning instead of using a `X-` header which is the practice when you invent your own headers.